# Gerar números aleatórios

Tags: array, ruby-on-rails, ruby, random

Tenho o seguinte problema:

- Preciso gerar um número aleatório entre 1 e 6
- Atribuir a um *array* de números caso este novo não esteja contido no *array*
- Caso esteja contido, gerar novamente. Fazer esse processo até que o *array* de números tenha 6 números

Comment: não entendi o ultimo caso, você não quer que eles se repitam caso gerem novamente? @DaniloTiagoThaiSantos

Comment: No caso, é apenas um array de números que não se repitam, vou usar a função (1..6).to_a.shuffle

Comment: Boa, então a resposta do Guigs te atende :), marca como certa depois se te ajudou

Comment: Alguma resposta te serviu, se sim aceite ela como solução do seu problema ???

Answer (score 6):

Você está pensando já em como implementar em forma procedural. Pelo que entendi você quer um array com os números de 1 a 6 em ordem aleatória. Para isso use o método [Array#shuffle](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-shuffle).

```
(1..6).to_a.shuffle
=> [6, 3, 5, 4, 1, 2]
```

Comment: É isso mesmo que eu preciso, obrigado !

Answer (score 1):

Para gerar números aleatórios use o método `rand`, ele gera um número decimal de 0.0 até 1.0 se for usado sem argumentos.

Para usar com inteiros passe um parâmetro inteiro dessa forma:

```
rand NUM_INT
```

Isso vai gerar um número de 0 até NUM_INT - 1.

Você também pode gerar números aleatórios em um determinado intervalo!

Por exemplo, para ter números entre 50 e 100:

```
rand 50..101
```